# ALAssetsLibrary is too slow while getting thumbnail image

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Using ALAssetsLibrary the Thumbnail images takes time to load.is there any solution to load images faster.
the images are more than 900 images in photos.
Code:

```
[ALAssetsGroupObj enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger i, BOOL *load)
{         
  if(asset == nil) 
  {
     asset;
  }
  UIImage* thumbImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail]
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you give us more context on what you intend to do : do you really need to load 900 images upfront ? Can't you let the user choose **which** pictures he wants (with UIImagePickerController) ?

Comment: Yes i am creating custom galleryView like UIImagePickerController,and loading thumbnail images in tableview.

Comment: Then, as suggested by @BlueVoodoo : consider loading chunks of data as the user scrolls. But why can't you use UIImagePickerController in the first place ? (sorry to insist :)

Comment: i want to select one image & then dismiss image picker immediately.And we can not get thumbnail image from UIImagePickerController

Comment: We get image date in NSData if image size is large (e.g more than 2-3 MB) it takes to long time to prepare that image.if i use ALAssetsLibrary i can get the thumbnail image and immediately dismiss that controller and prepare image background.

Comment: I see... then I think BlueVoodoo gave you the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to make it go any faster. But there are a few tricks:

1. Cache them to a static NSDictionary. Next time you'll need to draw them in your app, it will be much faster than pulling them from the library. I've tried with far more than 900 thumbnails.
2. Your screen won't fit 900 thumbs. As the user scrolls, you can populate the images in blocks and load say 16-32 or so per time. This is a bit tricky though as both the operation to draw the thumbnails and the scrolling needs to run on the main thread.

Comment: Yes i am creating custom galleryView like UIImagePickerController,and loading thumbnail images in tableview.

Comment: I suspected so. Then these are your options.